# C# json deserialiser how to set property

Tags: c#, json, properties

My code is:

```
namespace RTT_API
{
    class routepoint
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string TIPLOC { get { return TIPLOC; } set { SetStationRef(); } }
        public string publicTime { get; set; }
        public Guid StationRef { get; set; }
       
        public void SetStationRef()
        {
            SqlCommand comStationRef = new SqlCommand("select uniqueref from station where tiploc=@tiploc", Globals.RTTConn);
            comStationRef.Parameters.Add("@tiploc");
            comStationRef.Parameters["@tiploc"].Value = TIPLOC;
            SqlDataReader rdrStationRef = comStationRef.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdrStationRef.HasRows == true)
            {
                rdrStationRef.Read();
                StationRef = rdrStationRef.GetGuid(1);
                rdrStationRef.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                rdrStationRef.Close();
                comStationRef.CommandText="Insert into station(tiploc) values (@tiploc)";
                comStationRef.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            rdrStationRef.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate help with the following:

- If I try to debug the TIPLOC value I receive a Stackoverflow error. It worked OK when the definition was only:

```
public string TIPLOC { get; set; }
```

- The `SetStationRef` method doesn't run when the value is set
- The `TIPLOC` value is set by a JSON deserialise command. Is using a custom 'set' method the correct way to set the `StationRef` value? I tried putting code in the class constructor but it looks like the constructor runs before the JSON deserialise sets the properties? I'm new to C# so trying not to get into any bad practices to start with.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line
`public string TIPLOC { get { return TIPLOC; } set { SetStationRef(); } }`
will return TIPLOC indefinitely because it is calling itself. Calling return TIPLOC will call the getter of TIPLOC and its just going to keep doing that until it overflows the stack. When you debug the debugger will try and retrieve the value of the property and will get stuck in that loop.

`set { SetStationRef(); }` also ignores the value. I assume you want to call `SetStationRef(value);`. In the setter of a property the value the user is trying to set gets passed in as a local variable called `value`

From the overall look I think what you are trying to achieve is something along the lines of

```
private string tiploc; 
public string TIPLOC
{
   get 
   {
       if(tiploc == null)
       {
           tiplock = GetValueFromDatabase(); // Replace this to retrieve the value
       }

       tiploc;
   }
   set 
   {
        SetStationRef(value);
        tiploc = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I understand why I am getting the Stackoverflow error. The process that I'm trying to setup is Part 1) The TIPLOC string is set by the JSON (I can get that to work on it's own, I break it when I try part 2.  Part 2) When the TIPLOC is set then some code runs which gets the StationRef from the SQL database and stores it in the StationRef property. The things I'm trying to avoid a) Repeatedly querying the database for the StationRef b) Get the StationRef set automatically when the TIPLOC is set to avoid the potential for one to be set without the other.

Comment: Not a problem at all, can you accept the answer if it helped you thanks?

Comment: I'm new to Stackoverflow and not sure of all of the processes. I'm still working on part 2 (from my comment). That may lead to me needing to update my question and other answers. I tried to ask on Meta about the processes but it's not letting me at the moment. I don't want to incorrectly lose the credit due to you for your help or close the question too early.

Comment: Not a problem :) I've updated my answer to avoid repeated queries.

Answer (score 0):

My original three questions were:

1. If I try to debug the TIPLOC value I receive a Stackoverflow error
2. The SetStationRef method doesn't run when the value is set -
3. The TIPLOC value is set by a JSON deserialise command. Is using a custom 'set' method the correct way to set the StationRef value? I tried putting code in the class constructor but it looks like the constructor runs before the JSON deserialise sets the properties? I'm new to C# so trying not to get into any bad practices to start with.

Question 1 was answered by Ben and his help enabled me to find a solution to questions 2 and 3 so a lot of credit is due to him.

I've only added a separate answer because the custom accessor needs to be defined on the StationRef and not the Tiploc (the Tiploc is set by the Deserialisation code) as follows:

```
public string tiploc { get; set; }
        public Guid StationRef

        {
            get
            {
                if (stationRef == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    stationRef = Globals.GetStationRef(tiploc); 
                }
                return stationRef;
            }
            set
            {
                stationRef = value;
            }
        }
```